# Trouble constructing an ordered set that is not directed

Tags: ordered-fields

I want to try to construct an ordered set that is not directed to give myself a better understanding of what it means to be directed. Any good examples out there?

Comment: Just take a set with two elements and have them be not comparable.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft ??? There's no requirement that any two elements be comparable in a directed set. "Directed set" is not the same as "linearly ordered set".

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The point is that Tobias' example is *not* directed, since there is no upper bound of those two elements.

Comment: @NoahSchweber ??? Consider the power set of $\Bbb Z$, ordered by inclusion. The two elements $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are not comparable. But this _is_ a directed set - any two elements $a$ and $b$ havve an upper bound, for example $a\cup b$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I explicitly said that the set should have two elements.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I read "has two elements" as "has at least two elements". Yes, if you meant "has exactly two elements" then yes, that's a trivial example.

Answer (score 0):

Trivial example: Let $S$ be any set with at least two elements, and deine a partial order on $S$ by saying $x\le y$ if and only if $x=y$.

More informative example:  Consider the set of all $A\subset\Bbb Z$ such that $A$ has at most $3$ elements, ordered by inclusion.

Comment: This is **exactly** the order Tobias described.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I didn't realize he meant "has exactly two elements". (If the possibility of reading what he wrote that way had occurred to me I would have assumed that was what he meant...)